# Member Reference Base Type Not a Structure or Union

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, nodes

I am declaring an array of MyNode in my .h as `MyNode **myArray;`.

Then in my .cpp, I have `myArray = new MyNode*[1];`.

Whenever I try to call `myArray.size()` or `myArray.resize()`, I get the error:

member reference base type 'MyNode **' is not a structure or union

Any ideas why I am getting this error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in C++ do not have methods that you can call on them

If you want to do operations like that - then use a container like:

```
std::vector<MyNode> myArray(1)
```

Or, if you will not be changing the size of the array dynamically:

```
std::array<MyNode, 12> myArray;
```

Comment: or use `std::array`, if you really want an array.